# What is a good stack/cms for a java based enterprise intranet?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, content-management-system, ecm, hippocms

I am considering [hippo](http://www.onehippo.org)

It need to have a debian/ubuntu friendly licence.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Hippo CMS is Apache licensed, so in that sense an option for you. 
If you want to get started, go to: http://www.onehippo.org/

Answer (score 1):

I read that [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-portal) is one of the best open source Java-based portals. Also it's specifically designed be useful for enterprise use.

Also it's licensed under the MIT-License.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your exact needs but without more details, I'd add Alfresco, Nuxeo and Exo to your list.

#### Related questions

- [Can you recommend an easy to use easy to develop CMS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939238/can-you-recommend-an-easy-to-use-easy-to-develop-cms)
- [Which is easier to extend, Alfresco or Nuxeo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943509/which-is-easier-to-extend-alfresco-or-nuxeo)
- [Looking for a good programmable Java CMS (Content Management System)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174131/looking-for-a-good-programmable-java-cms-content-management-system)

#### See also

- [Alfresco vs Nuxeo : True Open Source](http://forums.alfresco.com/en/viewtopic.php?t=8993)
- [Nuxeo vs. Alfresco, How Do You Like Your OSS?](http://www.cmswire.com/cms/enterprise-cms/nuxeo-vs-alfresco-how-do-you-like-your-oss-001254.php)
- [Stephane Croisier: The Future of Open Source CMS](http://cmsreport.com/content/2010/05/stephane-croisier-future-open-source-cms)

Comment: Interesting links (some don't work anymore) and also interesting to see how Alfresco and Nuxeo developed over the past 7 years. I have written a Medium article why I switched from Alfresco to Nuxeo, as of 2017: https://medium.com/mathias-conradt/dumping-alfresco-for-nuxeo-as-my-preferred-document-management-system-2116cf421d36#.qeln6qot1